# Can you declare variable at runtime with Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I currently have a series of tests that are functional and I want to be able to declare 1 of 2 options at runtime.  The tests are currently using XVFB and running headlessly.

The current code that operates the browser is:

```
Start Virtual Display and enter the URL
    [Documentation]  Test creates virtual display using XVFB
    [Arguments]    ${URL}
    start virtual display  1440  900
    Open Browser  ${URL}
    set window size  1440  900
    sleep  ${delay}
```

If I comment out the `start virtual display  1440  900` step, the test case will automatically call the native browser to execute the test steps.

I was hoping there would be an "easy way" to comment or uncomment the `start virtual display` test step - maybe by declaring it as a variable?

Answer (score 3):

You can set variable from command line: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-variables-in-command-line

Isn't it enough?

Edit based on your code sample:

```
Start Virtual Display and enter the URL
    [Documentation]  Test creates virtual display using XVFB
    [Arguments]    ${URL}
    Run Keyword If    '${vd}' == 'TRUE'    Start Virtual Display    1440    900
    Open Browser    ${URL}
    Set Window Size    1440    900
    Sleep    ${delay}
```

And then call your tests with `--variable vd:TRUE`

Comment: Sorry - I didnt do a good job describing my actual scenario - will modify my original question to clarify.

Comment: Answer extended.

Comment: Thanks Jan!  This is exactly what I am looking to do, however the only remaining question now is now to pass that variable through the bash script being run in Jenkins.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Jenkins at all. I can imagine you'd setup two plans (or one plan with two configurations?) for both options.

Answer (score 0):

In your updated question it seems to me that you are looking for `Run Keyword If` functionality that will allow you to use the value of a variable specified on the command line when starting RF to determine the execution of your script. More on the Run Keyword If can be found [here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If)

Answer (score 0):

You can create two tests cases, the first without ***start virtual display  1440  900***.
and the other test you set to use ***start virtual display  1440  900*** keyword